# Binary tree parent same as in order first output

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

So i have a question that is confusing me.

It says that the **INORDER** traversal output of a binary tree is `[2,5,4,8,1,6,3,7]`.

The **PREORDER** traversal output of the **SAME** tree is `[2,1,4,5,8,3,6,7]`.

Using this 2 output, i have to find the postorder  and construct the binary tree.

I know that the first element of preorder is the root of the binary tree.

If so, how can it be possible that the **root** of the binary tree is the **first** element of **inorder** traversal output as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If root only has one child node on its right side.

Comment: Well snap.. i certainly did not think of that . Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The tree that is represented is:

[image]

As you can see, it is quite possible that both orders list the root as first node. In-order lists the left subtree first, then the node (root) itself, and then the right subtree. If there is no left subtree (like in the image above), then the first output will be the node itself.

And as you already know preorder will anyway output the root first.

Comment: Thank you for the photo for visualisation.